# I need to schedule a function in a future

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodebb

I want to schedule a function in a future. This is my code:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                function();
                console.log("UNO");
            }, 5000);
```

But I don't like this solution, so Anyone know some method in nodejs that I use to schedule a function in the future?

Comment: What don't you like about it?

Comment: Is it broken or causing problems?

Comment: Why put the function in another function? Can't you just add the console.log to function() itself?, that would make it a nicer solution.

Comment: Because if I restart server, the timeout is detroied!

Comment: `Because if I restart server, the timeout is detroied!` Please update your question with important information such as this that could explain exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe hire a personal assistant.

Comment: No need to offload the function, but you either need the timer to run in another place (ie. redis queue) or use `setTimeout` and check the current time to see if the function should run or not.

Answer (score 2):

There is this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule

Also, you could set interval of 1 second (or millisecond or hour or whatever depending on precision you need) and inside of it check current time. If time is right, you trigger function.

Answer (score 1):

Use can use [node-schedule package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

```
var scheduler = require('node-schedule');

var date = new Date(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

var newYearJob = scheduler.scheduleJob(date, function() {
 console.log("Happy new year");
});
```

In case not needed

```
newYearJob.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/agenda

With this package the scheduler will still work after system or script restart thanks to persitant storage (MongoDB, Redis, ...)